# Odoo CMS is supposed to run "globally installed npm module" but it is some how looking into rbenv in mac os.

Tags: python, node.js, macos, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to install a module in "Odoo version 8" CMS which has a npm dependency. Thus i installed the dependency using following code:

```
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

But it shows following error which looks like "Odoo" is looking into wrong path (inside rbenv path) rather then using globally installed npm module.

Error code:

```
/Users/roshankarki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/less-2.6.0/bin/lessc:83:in `<top (required)>': invalid option: --clean-css (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
 from /Users/roshankarki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/lessc:23:in `load'
 from /Users/roshankarki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/lessc:23:in `<main>'
 This error occured while compiling the bundle 'website.assets_frontend' containing:
 - /website_less/static/src/less/import_bootstrap.less
 - /website_less/static/src/less/colors.less
 - /website_less/static/src/less/website.less";
```

Odoo Module getting installed which resulted in error: 
  -Theme Support Engine (website_less) module

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error and the solution to fix it is to uninstall the ruby version. In your case this command can help you:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.1.0
```